# Windows - safe to call CloseHandle() when an Overlapped I/O is in progress?

Tags: c, windows, handle, msdn, writefile

I have a program that has multiple threads which need to use the same handle (it is opened with FILE_SHARE_READ) to write. What happens if one thread closes the handle while another currently has an I/O in progress (WriteFile, in my case)? Does CloseHandle block until the write finishes?

The MSDN documentation seems very sparse on this topic.

Comment: The clean solution is to let the thread which started the overlapped I/O clean up as well. And use a dedicated thread for it.

Comment: I agree, but this will not work in my instance. The application is written to have multiple threads which issue I/O to the same handle because it is opened with GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE and FILE_SHARE_READ. I cannot use a lock on the handle because I'd need to hold it during an I/O, which will not work for many reasons.

Comment: @Lundin - i be say this is bad solution. call `CloseHandle` is the best way for cancel all pending I/O (begin from vista always and usual on xp). and we never need dedicated thread, never need wait, etc

Comment: @RbMm A dedicated thread means you won't have to poll, nor do you have to interrupt the main thread. That thread will be asleep most of the time, only waking up when receiving an event. You don't "have" to use a thread, but it is a more professional solution than just relying on callbacks.

Comment: @Lundin of course we never must poll. however exist solution, where we not use any dedicated threads, never wait - use callback and have 100% asynchronous io. and why you think that use and relying on callbacks not professional ? just interesting

Comment: @RbMm Because they interrupt the program. If you have a single-threaded program with GUI and overlapped I/O, then the I/O might cause GUI lag. Especially true for serial communication and other slow things, that you may need to parse "on the fly".

Comment: @Lundin - "interrupt the program" - what mean ? if we use single thread GUI overlapped I/O - this mean that we use APC completion and have message loop based on alertable wait in `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx`. when we have I/O complete apc callback will be called (this you mean "interrupt program" ?) where we say can start next I/O and exit from callback. with iocp completion we use thread pool and no any problems. with serial port or say soft pipes here of course all ok, speed of communication not play any role, because we never way for io complete. not need any dedicated thread anyway

Comment: i not once use different asynchronous I/O, write special libs for this, always rely on callbacks, never poll or wait. and all is just fine

Comment: @RbMm You still need to handle the data. If you have for example a serial input and you need to echo each character, then that means one callback per character, after which you need to run some code - how complex the code is depends on the application. And code must be executed by a thread - it cannot execute in thin air without a CPU. So naturally the speed of the communication makes a big difference, because at higher speeds you'll get more frequent callbacks that you'll need to handle, by executing code, which you cannot do in thin air still. Threads make all the difference.

Comment: @Lundin - if we need relative long time for process result of I/O - yes, exist sense pass this task to another thread if we use apc callback. if we use iocp callbacks with thread pool (i prefer this way and relative rarely use apc completion) - in general we can do this just in callback. here implementation logic depend from concrete task. possible of course use and dedicated thread(s) for io, but in this case usually it not need have asynchronous io - but synchronous

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how close the I/O is to completion, it could either complete normally or be cancelled.  Or if there's a non-zero usage count on the kernel file object (e.g. `DuplicateHandle()` was used), those operations could proceed normally until the other handle is also closed.

`CloseHandle()` may block, but if you really want to wait for completion (success or cancellation) of the pending I/O, wait on the event HANDLE in its OVERLAPPED structure after calling `CloseHandle()`.

Good additional information: https://community.osr.com/discussion/213975

Comment: I can have it handle whatever the result is, I just want to verify that no really bizarre results come back (e.g. GetOverlappedResult says the I/O completed successfully when it really didn't).

Answer (score 3):

from system view - this is correct, safe, ok call `CloseHandle` at any time. this independed from are exist some I/O request in progress on file to which this handle pointed. even more call `CloseHandle` the best way (*begin from vista, on xp - this is driver depended, usual I/O canceled in this case too*) cancel all pending I/O requests

> What happens if one thread closes the handle while another currently
>   has an I/O in progress

if this is not last handle to file - nothing hapen. otherwise (this is usual case and think you mean exactly this case - you have single handle open on file) the `IRP_MJ_CLEANUP` handler will be called in driver (which create device objec, on which your file created). then already is no general and common answer - driver specific. however most windows built-in drivers at this point just complete with some error (usual with `STATUS_CANCELLED` but not always, say *npfs.sys* (pipe driver) use `STATUS_PIPE_BROKEN` error here) all pending requests and return control. on xp/2003 - this is all. so this is driver duty complete all pending requests at this point. however some 3-th party drivers can and not do this - so some I/O can still be pending (undefined time) after handle closed. but begin from vista here was major change. the [`FILE_OBJECT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545834(v=vs.85).aspx) was extended (on xp/2003 the `CompletionContext` was last field) - added `IrpList`. now inside [`FILE_OBJECT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545834(v=vs.85).aspx) system mantain list of some active I/O request on file. when we send asynchronous IRP request it queued to Thread (always before vista) or to `FILE_OBJECT` - if IOCP port accosiated with this file object, ApcContext not 0 (from win32 view - pointer to `OVERLAPPED` not 0) and no user event in IRP (from win32 view OVERLAPPED.hEvent == 0). this affect when system cancel IRP - when thread exit or when last file handle closed. in vista, after `IRP_MJ_CLEANUP` handler return - system check `IrpList` and if it not empty - call `IoCancelIrp` for every Irp from this list. of course than again driver depended, but all well design drivers (including all microsoft drivers) when return pending for request (Irp) mandatory register [CancelRoutine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-iosetcancelroutine) to be called if the specified IRP is canceled. this routine called when system call `IoCancelIrp` (if not removed before) and inside this routine driver complete request with `STATUS_CANCELLED`. this mean that if driver not complete Irp inside `IRP_MJ_CLEANUP` - system by self cancel this irp just after `IRP_MJ_CLEANUP` return and this cause that driver anyway complete this Irp inside it `CancelRoutine`

so conclusion - close last handle on file (last call `CloseHandle` ) is effective way for cancell all I/O requests on this file (with some exceptions on xp and only for 3-rd party drivers).this is legal, safe and effective (if we want cancell al io and close file)

> Does CloseHandle block until the write finishes?

because inside this call called driver supplied `IRP_MJ_CLEANUP` handler - can be all. even block. but if say about built-in windows drivers - this never happens. and even for 3-rd party drivers - i never view this behaviour. so in practic - `CloseHandle` not block and not wait when all I/O requests on file finished

so call `CloseHandle` is safe at any time, but here exist another problem, not related to system design but related to your code design. in your code (and usual) handle is shared resourse - several different threads will use it. and this is usual problem, when object (handle in your case) used by several threads - who and when must close handle. what happens if one your thread close handle when another thread begin I/O request with this handle, after it was closed ? you or got `STATUS_INVALID_HANDLE` from api call, if handle not valid at this time. but possible and more bad case. after you close handle - some another code can create another object. and for new created object will be assigned the last closed handle ( system use stack model for free handles). as result handle can be already valid when you begin I/O operation (after close handle from another thread), but.. this handle already will point to another object. if this is not file object handle (say event or thread handle) - you got `STATUS_OBJECT_TYPE_MISMATCH` from I/O request. in whe worst case - this will be file object handle, but for another file. so you can begin I/O operation with another file and unpredicatable result (say write data to another, arbitrary file).

so you need somehow protect or synchronize shared handle usage and closing, between threads. first think here - use reference counting for handle and call `CloseHandle` when no more reference. but this is not usable on practic - if say some thread permanent do I/O on file(pipe) (say read from it, when read complete - just call another read and so on) - we have no chance call `CloseHandle` from another thread.

for concrete example we call [`ReadDirectoryChangesW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-readdirectorychangesw) for file asynchronous. when this call complete - just again call `ReadDirectoryChangesW` and so on. gow break this loop ? set some stop flag and call [`CancelIoEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/cancelioex-func) ? but possible that [`CancelIoEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/cancelioex-func) will be called in between 2 calls of `ReadDirectoryChangesW`, whe really no any I/O on file. so it nothing cancel.. effective way stop this - call `CloseHandle`, but if we do this without protection - exist risk that next call to [`ReadDirectoryChangesW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-readdirectorychangesw) will be use arbitrary object (handle value will be the same, but it will be invalid or point to another object). use reference counting - not way here - who permanent call `ReadDirectoryChangesW` need have own reference and reference never rich 0. so we never call `CloseHandle` and never break loop.

the effective and nice solution here - use [Run-Down Protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/run-down-protection) for handle. unfortunatelly not api in user mode for support this, but not hard yourself [implement](https://github.com/rbmm/LIB/blob/master/INC/rundown.h) this

possible usage (if implement exactly how this implemented in kernel)

threads before use `m_hFile`, protected by `m_RunRef`, do next code

```
ULONG dwError = ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE;

if (AcquireRundownProtection(&m_RunRef))
{
  // use m_hFile in some I/O request
  // for example
  // dwError = ReadDirectoryChangesW(m_hFile, ..);
  ReleaseRundownProtection(&m_RunRef);
}
```

thread which want close handle do next

```
WaitForRundownProtectionRelease(&m_RunRef);
CloseHandle(m_hFile);
```

note that `WaitForRundownProtectionRelease` wait not when all I/O complete but only when all another threads exit from `AcquireRundownProtection / ReleaseRundownProtection` block. also after call `WaitForRundownProtectionRelease` `AcquireRundownProtection` always return false - so prevent new acquire and what for release existing.

however i prefer another implementation for begin rundown:

asynchronous call to `BeginRundown(&m_RunRef)` (after which all new `AcquireRundownProtection` return false) - but not wait at this place. end when rundown completed - callback will be called. and inside this callback we safe call `CloseHandle` - no new usage of handle at this place, and all old usage of handle (in io call) already completed. note - usage of handle completed - not mean I/O completed - it in progress maybe. but handle need only for start I/O